# Which Function Satisfies These Conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The graph of a non-negative differentiable function passes through the origin and through the point $(1,2/\pi)$. If, for every $x>0$, the ordinate set of $f$ above the interval $[0,x]$ sewwps out a solid of volume $x^2 f(x)$ when rotated about the $x$-axis, find the function $f$.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the volume of a solid of revolution?

Comment: How is this problem much different from the second part of this question I just answered for you  (which solution you thanked me for and you have yet to accept, much like most of your other 37 questions): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457941/a-problem-about-areas-and-volumes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V(x)$ is the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the graph of $f$ from $0$ to $x$, then $$V(x)=\pi\int_0^xf(y)^2dy$$

Therefore the problem reduces to solve the equation $$V(x)=x^2 f(x),\ \ f(0)=0, f(1)=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Note that the value in zero is redundant.

Comment: Yes, it is @TZakrevskiy

Comment: And, $V(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \pi f^2(t) dt$. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right @SaaqibMahmuud